# Is there a way for me to fill between 2 ccDrawCircle's and what is the segments parameter?

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

On cocos2d-iphone, I can use ccDrawCircle to draw circles. What I don't know how to do is to fill between 2 ccDrawCircles that have the same ccp centre (sort of like a bicycle tire). I tried just using drawing a whole lot of ccdrawcircles in an attempt to get the effect i want but I'm hoping there is another way.

I'm also a little confused on what does the 'segments' parameter do for ccDrawCircle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone else who needs the answer to my questions, it is possible to write a while loop within an overridden draw method that is inherited within CCLayer. You just have to make sure you have the variables updated at your controller's update method.

```
-(void) draw
{
    ...
    self.currentInnerRadius= self.minimumInnerRadius;
    while (self.currentInnerRadius < self.OuterRadius) 
    {
        ccDrawCircle( ccp(x,y), self.currentInnerRadius, CC_DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(90), 100, NO);
        self.currentInnerRadius++;
    }
}
```

The segments parameter seems to be the number of triangle/vertices/segments you want to use to draw the circle. The higher the number, the 'smoother' your circle will be. Hopefully this helps someone else.

Cheers!